# Como soluciono este error de acceso a la ruta configurada en el webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net

Actualmente tengo una ruta configurada en el webconfig de mi solucion de asp.net:

```
public bool Upload(TblArchivosExpedienteDigital tblArchivosExpedienteDigital, string IdUsuario, HttpPostedFileBase request, string filename)
    {
        long response = 0;

        try
        {
            var fileContent = request.InputStream;
            var fileNameOriginal = Path.GetFileName(request.FileName);
            var fileNameVersion = expedienteDigitalDAL.FileNameLastVersion(tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente, tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento);
            fileNameVersion = string.Format("{0}{1}", fileNameVersion, Path.GetExtension(fileNameOriginal));

            string NombreNuevo = string.Empty;
            if (tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 48 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 1610 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 85 
                 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 74 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 12 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 77 || tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento == 78)
            {
                long vs = expedienteDigitalDAL.FileLastVersionInt(tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente, tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento) + 1;

                switch (tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento)
                {
                    //Avaluo
                    case 48:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Avaluo_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                    //ultima Escritura
                    case 1610:
                    case 85:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Escritura_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                    //Camara de Comercio
                    case 74:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Camara_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                    //Cert tradicion ppal
                    case 12:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Certificado_inmueble_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                    //Cert tradicion deposito
                    case 77:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Certificado_deposito_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                    //Cert tradicion garaje
                    case 78:
                        NombreNuevo = String.Format("Certificado_garaje_{0}_{1}.pdf", tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente.ToString(), vs.ToString());
                        break;
                }
                string NombreCompletoNuevoTcg = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExpedienteDigital"].ToString(), NombreNuevo);
                request.SaveAs(NombreCompletoNuevoTcg);
            }

            var uploaded = UploadFileToServer(tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente, fileContent, filename);

            if (uploaded)
            {
                response = expedienteDigitalDAL.UploadFileToDataBase(tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idExpediente, IdUsuario, tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.idDocumento, fileNameVersion, fileNameOriginal, tblArchivosExpedienteDigital.comentarios);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception ee = new Exception("Class: Files Method: Upload", ex);
            ExceptionManager.HandleException(ee, 1, 5000, 1);
            throw new Exception("Exception(Files): Upload file");
        }

        return response > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Pasa que al intentar el archivo al momento de hacer el guardo en la ruta me sale el siguiente error:
[image: Error al intentar guardar la imagen en la ruta especificada]

Específicamente me sale el siguiente error:
El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.

Actualmente tengo configurada la ruta así en mi webconfig:

```
<add key="ExpedienteDigital" value="\\198.22.43.33\Itau\" />
```

Quisiera saber que puede ser, porque sale error, si debo configurar un usuario de acceso a la ruta y como debo hacerlo

Comment: El error viene de la configuración del usuario que accede a la carpeta `Itau` de la máquina ubicada en la IP `198.22.43.33`. ¿Qué usuario utiliza la aplicación web para acceder a esta carpeta? Asegúrate de que las credenciales sean válidas.

Answer (score 1):

Esa ruta es un path de red, por lo general el usuario con el cual ejecuta el `application pool` del `IIS` no tiene acceso a esas rutas

Para tener acceso deberias impersonar el sitio, podrias hacerlo cambioando el usuario con el cual ejecuta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o podrias definirlo en el `web.config` para eso define la configuracion

```
<identity impersonate="true" 
      userName="domain\user"  
      password="password" />
```

indicando un usuario del dominio en que se encuentra el web server que tenga acceso a esa ruta de red

Comment: Al configurar lo que dices me sale el siguiente error: 

Línea 52:     <roleManager enabled="true" />
Línea 53:     <authentication mode="None" />
Línea 54:     <identity impersonate="true" userName="xxxxxxxx.col\diego.benitez" password="xxxxxx" />
Línea 55:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1">
Línea 56:       <buildProviders> Mensaje de error del analizador: No se puede crear el símbolo (token) de usuario de Windows con las credenciales especificadas en el archivo de configuración. Error del sistema operativo 'El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.

Comment: Entiendo indica que no defines las credenciales correctas. El servidor esta dentro del dominio que indicas en el userName ?